# Django - Dynamic view for url

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to load a particular view depending on the url, for example:

```
url(r'^channel/(?P<channel>\d+)/$', ---, name='channel_render'),
```

Depending on the channel passed into the url, I want to load a specific view file. I tried doing this:

```
def configure_view(channel):
    print channel

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^channel/(?P<channel>\d+)/$', configure_view(channel), name='channel_render'),
```

But obviously the channel argument is not getting passed in. Is there any way to do this? The only other solution I can think of is loading a manager view and then loading the relevant view file from there. If this is the only way, how do I redirect to another view file from within a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to load a view that functions as a tiny dispatcher, which calls the final view you're interested in.

As far as how to do that, views are just functions that get called in a particular way and expected to return a particular thing. You can call one view from another; just make sure you're properly returning the result.

You can load views from different files with `import`.

Comment: I'd rather load the view in the same way django does when the URL is resolved, just cold importing the view doesn't seem right? I'll have a look through the source code and see how django imports views, perhaps there is a function I can hijack.

Comment: Seems I could use import_module from django.utils.importlib. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this.

```
#urls.py
url(r'^channel/(?P<channel>\d+)/$', switcher, name='channel_render'),

#views.py
def switcher(request, channel):
    if channel == 'Whatever':
        return view_for_this_channel()

def view_for_this_channel()
    #handle like a regular view
```

If using class-based views, the call in your `switcher()` will look like this:

```
#views.py
def switcher(request, channel):
    if channel == 'Whatever':
        return ViewForThisChannel.as_view()(request)  # <-- call to CBV

def ViewForThisChannel(View):
    #handle like a regular class-based view
```

Answer (score 2):

For redirecting you should use the Django redirect shortcut function:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Answer (score 0):

try calling like a normal view e.g.

```
def configure_view(request, channel):
    print channel

url(r'^channel/(?P<channel>\d+)/$', configure_view, name='channel_render'),
```