# Django: dynamically mapping views in urls.py

Tags: python, django

I have a `views`directory containing say a hundred view files. How can i make my `urls.py` transfer control to these view files without putting in an "intermediate handler" as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073679/django-dynamic-view-for-url) (answered 3 years back).

Basically- is there a *cleaner way* for redirecting control to views in django?

Comment: I can't imagine any reason to have a hundred view files. Why would you have so many? I can't even imagine an app with a hundred views, let alone separate files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view function returns an HTML page that includes the current date and time. To display this view at a particular URL, you’ll need to create a URLconf; see URL dispatcher for instructions.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/

For redirecting you should use the Django redirect shortcut function

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect