# Don't manage to use a dynamic view for an url with Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls, keyerror

I'm trying to dynamically call a view for an url.
Let me precise this.
I would like to create some objects, in fact 'Exercises', and each one would need a view (because of a huge number of variables, which would be different from an exercise to another). I'm using a TemplateView for each exercise.
Actually, each one needs a different htlm too, but this one can be given in the view.

I tried the method found here : [Dynamic for url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073679/django-dynamic-view-for-url)

Here is the code that interest us :
I precise that each exercise of the class Exercise (in models.py) would have at least one attribute called wanted_view which would indicate the wanted view for the exercise.

example.html (which contains the link to an exercise) :

```html
{% for exercise in list_exercise %}
... 
<a href="{% url 'vue_exercise' exercise.id exercise.wanted_view %}"> The link to the wanted exercise </a>
...
{% endfor %}
```

where list_exercise is a context variable of example.html which contains all the objects of the class Exercise.

urls.py :

```
...
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^exercise/(?P<exercise_id>\d+)/(?P<channel>\w+)/$', views.switcher, name='vue_exercise'),
]
```

Here a dynamic url which waits for exercise_id (here exercise.id) and channel (here exercise.wanted_view).

views.py :

```
def switcher(request, channel):
    if channel == 'TheFamousWantedView':
        return TheFamousWantedView.as_view()(request) 

class TheFamousWantedView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'wanted_template.html'
    context_object_name = ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        exercise = Exercise.objects.get(id=kwargs['exercise_id'])
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['exercise'] = exercise
        return context
```

Here we build the view of the exercise, which brings back the id of the exercise, to be able to show some specific informations related to this one.

The problem i got comes with the switcher function which has to call the good view.
I have this error :

**switcher() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exercise_id'**

Moreover, would i be able to make a function like the switcher one, for which i wouldn't have to create IF conditions for each view, like above with the "if channel == 'TheFamousWantedView' ...) ??

Solution 1 : I modified my function in this way

```
def switcher(request, niveau_id, channel):
    if channel == 'TheFamousWantedView':
        return TheFamousWantedView.as_view()(request)
```

TheFamousWantedView is called now, so that's cool, but there is another problem. The kwargs dictionary seems to have been emptied and there is now a KeyError raised that tells me that the exercise_id isn't known... That worked perfectly before i defined that switcher function.

Any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

```
def switcher(request, channel):
```

This function is receiving only one argument from your url `channel`, the argument `exercise_id` is not being received properly. You have to handle it anyways even if you're not gonna do anything with it.

```
def switcher(request, exercise_id, channel):
```

And for the "Moreover", I think you can create a model with the those channel and have a field for something similar to `template_name`. Then in your function call the template after getting the proper channel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, add exercise_id in the argument in this way seems to have made things better. However, i get a new error 'KeyError' with the exercise_id in the get_context_data of TheFamousWantedView... Do you know why ?